# Google Hangouts chrome extension transparency issue in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, chrome

I just installed the Google Hangouts chrome extension (the one that looks like Facebook's Messenger pop-up heads). Unfortunately, all the circles have a white box around it, as if transparency is not working. Has anybody else noticed this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

What video card, if any, do you have? Are you using the default video driver, or have you installed proprietary drivers. Often installing the proprietary driver can fix issues like this. If you are using a newer Nvidia card, I'd suggest installing the latest driver, as Mint will most likely be using nouveau (reverse engineered open source drivers) by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539344/is-it-possible-to-remove-new-google-hangouts-apps-white-background).

Apparently it's impossible as of now. You won't get animations either. I don't know why this is but that was what was said in the linked post on the answer to that question.